# Error in 2023 Developer Survey analysis?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2023

The [2023 Developer Survey](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2023/#section-top-paying-technologies-top-paying-technologies) results page says *Erlang is the highest-paid language to know this year* but Zig is 1st:

[image]

---

**Add**

The above error is fixed but [this one](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2023/#section-most-popular-technologies-integrated-development-environment) still remains: *Visual Studio Code remains the preferred IDE across all developers, increasing its use among all developers this year from 75% to 81%*, there's no 81% value anywhere:

[image]

Comment: I'd expect that to be the smallest of the mistakes. If you take a look at [salaries by country](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2023/?utm_source=banner&utm_medium=display&utm_campaign=dev-survey-results-2023&utm_content=survey-results#salary-germany), marketing people are earning twice as much as C-level people in Germany, and more importantly, their salary increased from 59k ([2022 result](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022#salary-germany)) to 192k this year.

Comment: "In India, educators claim top salaries" This "highlight" is based on a single (1) [response](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2023/#salary-india). I wouldn't trust anything about this survey to be honest.

Comment: @ayhan Wow! I would never have thought to look at the sample sizes. That's crazy! Maybe they need to add automated warnings to the results. "Warning: Small sample size of 1".

Comment: this year's survey results look surprisingly skewed. i'd have liked them to review other benchmarks before sharing. And, have some methods to detect outliers. e.g., In India, **1 educator** stated a "super-high" salary which is nowhere close to the general truth, but was considered as a source of truth for some reason.

Comment: @Clonkex why would they? Then it would be obvious their results are meaningless, that would reduce engagement and lower the relevance of the entire thing. This is just a perfect of example of why you should never blindly trust statistics and unfortunately SO / SE produces misleading statistics all the time.

Comment: @luk2302 I thought I wasn't blindly trusting. In previous years the results have appeared reasonable when I checked, so I mistakenly assumed they were trustworthy. Now I'm kind of disappointed in SE (as if I didn't have reason for that already). I would have thought they would at least try to be honest with their survey results. You can still get meaningful data from it as long as you exclude the really small sample sizes so I don't see why they would hide it. (It's also worth mentioning that if I were basing decisions or outcomes on those statistics, I would have looked much closer.)

Comment: @Clonkex: Why attribute to malice what can easily be attributed to incompetence? I'd bet they just did a rush job of putting the results together this year...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Definitely. I guess the whole idea was to quickly put together something that can be used to jump on the AI train. That's why the survey was live for a much shorter period this year and AI section has its own blog where things like sample size etc were taken into account (i.e. "*Data only shown if sample size is more than 50 respondents*".)

Comment: @ayhan: I prefer to avoid attributing intent, I don't read minds. I'm just disappointed is all :(

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm not (intentionally) attributing anything to malice. In fact, the opposite. I'm suggesting in my response to luk2302 that I don't see any reason that they would have to hide how small the sample sizes are in some cases. But speaking of rush jobs, my comment was one. "Honest" was the wrong word and I knew it. What I should have said is something like: "I would have thought they would at least try to display the results in a meaningful way." I fully believe there was no malice or lack of integrity, only a stunning lack of care for how the results are displayed and interpreted.

Comment: My money is on Raku (a.k.a. Perl6). Employers get the highest level of experience and the lowest median salary (excepting Cobol/Delphi). Easily the most cost-effective way to fix Unicode glitches in your datastream.